# Google Places API - RadarSearch results are confusing

Tags: api, google-places-api

I'm running a query vs the Google Places RadarSearch API and don't entirely understand the results. I'm trying to find nearby Tesco Supermarkets. My query is structured like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=51.503186,-0.126446&types=store&keyword=tesco&name=tesco&radius=5000&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I've tried a bunch of variations of the fields types, keyword and name. None of the results are Tesco stores. Am i missing something?

The Google docs show the fields as:

*keyword — A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this place, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content.*

*name — One or more terms to be matched against the names of places, separated by a space character. Results will be restricted to those containing the passed name values. Note that a place may have additional names associated with it, beyond its listed name. The API will try to match the passed name value against all of these names. As a result, places may be returned in the results whose listed names do not match the search term, but whose associated names do.*

I always get the maximum of 200 results which maybe includes 1 or 2 Tescos. When I check on Google maps there are 10 Tescos in the radius I am searching. It's as if the api is ignoring the name field. It doesn't matter what I populate in the name field, I still get the same results

UPDATE: Seems this is a known bug https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7082

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am wrong, but I believe it is a commercial issue, google will show all business filtering them with a particular criteria they are no publishing the rules, for example in your search, the type you used was "store" , so they are returning to you all stores, and using the name or keyword in their own way who knows which criteria they are internally using, and there is something else, on the API description, the sample that they provide for radar search shows the name of the place in the result, but in the tests i am doing, they are not even sending the name, so you couldn't iterate those results, and filter by your own, for you to get the name, you have to do another call using:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJq4lX1doEdkgR5JXPstgQjc0&key=YOUR_KEY
```

Maybe there is another way but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I find the radar search is returning strange results today. It worked differently a couple of days ago.

The keyword-parameter has no effect at the moment and I have breaking integration-tests that were working before. I hope this is a temporary issue.

I filed a bug report for it: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7086

Comment: Now it's working again, google seems to have fixed the issue. All tests are running again. Cool!